# Reverse Array without Reverse Method - Exercise from Eloquent Javascript Book

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reverse an array without using reverse method, but am encountering a behavior I do not understand when using pop and push functions together.  Can someone explain why I am seeing the result I receive?

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
  let newArray = []
  array.map((num)=> {
    newArray.push(array.pop())
  })
  return newArray
}
    
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Result is

```
// [object Array] (3)
[5,4,3]
```

This is driving me nuts, I'm wondering if it is something I'm not understanding with the return values of map, pop or push mutating the original array?  This is an exercise from the book Eloquent Javascript, I have reversed an array in other ways before.  I want to avoid using a loop if at all possible, so if there are any ideas for how to solve this that do not involve a loop it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `.map()` is completely the wrong tool here. It goes through each element of the array. And you change the array underneath it. Moreover, you're not performing mapping with it, which is a dead giveaway it's wrong. For the record, `.filter()`, `.some()`, `.every()`, etc., including `.forEach()` are also not correct.

Comment: You're overthinking it.  Don't use `pop` at all.  Loop over the array in reverse (from `length - 1` to `0`) and `push` its elements to a new array.

Comment: First and foremost directly mutating input parameter is not a good practice, and pop mutates your array be careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `.pop()`, you're mutating the value of `array`, removing the last element of the array. This prevents you from fully iterating over the entire array. Once you're trying to loop the 4th time, the length of the array is 2 (`[1, 2]`) which is less than 4 which we would need to access the 3rd index, so it stops iterating. You can either do this using a normal `for` loop or by copying the array.

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
  const newArray = new Array(array.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArray[array.length-1 - i] = array[i];
  }
  return newArray;
}
    
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

or (but this is really weird, ***don't do this***)

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
  const copy = array.slice(0);
  const newArray = [];
  array.forEach((_) => {
    newArray.push(copy.pop());
  });
  return newArray
}
    
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand why what I was trying to do wasn't working!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
while (array.length) {
  newArray.push(array.pop());
}
```

There is no avoiding some kind of loop.

Comment: You're right!  No avoiding the loop

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it's easier to just traverse the array from the end:

```
for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    nums.push(array[i]);
}
```

Or, if you want to use instance methods built in:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    nums.push(array.pop());
}
```

Alternatively, you could also do it in-place, by swapping the elements:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    const tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: "*Or, if you want to use `map`*" yet, the code doesn't use `map`?

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly the solution from the book.  The swapping in place thing really blew my mind.